# How to collapse all if/else if/else statements within a method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, hotkeys

How can I collapse only the if/else if/else statements within one method at a time? I don't want to collapse all my code. Just the code within the method I am currently working in.

Comment: Collapse as in like hiding it in Visual Studio?

Comment: @maccettura Just like how I use Ctrl + M,O to collapse all methods down etc, I'm wondering if there is a similar hotkey that targets if/else statements

Comment: `Ctrl+M, Ctrl+M` will toggle the state of the collapsible construct where the cursor is.  Be sure to enable "Show outlining for code level constructs" if you disabled it; it's enabled by default (Tools, Options... / C# / Advanced).

Comment: All of the shortcuts are listed in the Edit > Outlining menu by default...

Comment: Not quite...  `Ctrl+M, Ctrl+X` (expand all) isn't in that menu.

Comment: Make 'em shorter ;-)

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll give it a go and take a look at the hotkeys

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now... like `Ctrl+M, O` for all blocks within the method. No, but you can do it in two steps. Put the cursor on the method's "`{`" or "`}`" and press `Ctrl+Shift+}`, then press `Ctrl+M, Ctrl+M`.

Comment: @madreflection that only does one if/else at a time right? what if I have like multiple if/else statements and want to collapse all of them at once?

Comment: No.  `Ctrl+Shift+}` selects the whole block, from `{` to `}`.  `Ctrl+M, Ctrl+M` will operate on the whole selection if there is one. Everything gets collapsed.

Comment: @madreflection You sir are a genius, thank you. That's what I was after

Comment: @madreflection Post it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no single keyboard shortcut that will collapse everything local to a single method but you can do it in two steps.

1. Put the cursor on the method's `{` or `}` and press `Ctrl+Shift+}` to select everything from `{` to `}`.
2. Press `Ctrl+M, Ctrl+M` to collapse the selection.

This can be done at any level of code.  You can select multiple methods, or just a single loop, and it will collapse that much.  `Ctrl+M, Ctrl+M` will collapse everything within the selection.  Or it'll expand it, since it's a toggle command.

Comment: Brilliant! Cheers mate.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the code you want collapsed inside of

```
#region
   code
#endregion
```

Comment: Nice idea but I want to collapse the whole else/if code block, then be able to open each else/if branch individually.

Comment: This might just be personal preference, and what has been forced down my throat, but people always told me to avoid regions. The reasoning was that if you needed regions, there's a chance your code hasn't been organized particularly well. Like, for a handful of methods in a class, it's benign. But if it's embedded into a function, it might be indicative of the issue I mentioned above. Really, it's not a big deal, but just something to consider.